# Add own claims when logging in with OIDC in ASP:NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, openid-connect

I use the OIDC middleware in ASP.NET Core with Cookies. This works just fine.
Now I need to add my own claims to the Context.User's Claims. I tried this:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
{
    ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ClientId"],
    ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ClientSecret"],
    Authority = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:Authority"],
    ResponseType = Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = "/signed-out",
    Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
    {
        OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async context =>
        {
            // Trying to add my claims here...
            // This must be wrong obviously
            context.HttpContext.User.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>() { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin") }));
        }
    }
});
```

Basically, I want to hook into the `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` event and add the claims. But this does not seem to work, as on further requests, the added identity is not on the context's User. How can I do this?

Comment: Ehm. Correct me if I am wrong, but when you receive the code, you don't have the token yet. You use the code + your client id/client secret to retrieve the token and you can't modify the received token, because that renders it invalid (token is signed by the server, any changes invalide the signature)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`OnTokenValidated`](https://joonasw.net/view/adding-custom-claims-aspnet-core-2) event instead.